# Test Flight receipts disappear after app restart

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

We are rolling out an app on Test Flight for internal testing. Our app has in-app subscriptions.
We are trying to test our restore purchases function, but after app restarts the receipt is gone. Is this normal behavior or are we doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One big caveat in the sandbox environment is that there is no receipt file on the device until a purchase is made. This differs from the production sandbox and production environments, where a receipt file is generated at the time of installation. To fully test restores in the sandbox, you need to add a button, gesture, or other means to revert the app to the unsubscribed state.

1. Subscribe to a monthly subscription.
2. Use a button/gesture to revert the app to the unsubscribed state.
3. Tap the “Restore Purchases” button.
4. If done before the 35-minute subscription cycle, an active subscription should be found, and the app should change to the subscribed state.

(Don't forget to remove button/gesture from #2 before releasing)

Comment: One of our receipts does stay existing on the device we are developing on.
Our development device has a receipt with an original purchase date back in december when we started development. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Could you link some sources we could read up on about sandbox receipts vs production?

Comment: The purchases remain in the receipt file, so you'll continue to see the `original_purchase_date` from the initial purchase - it's the receipt file itself that doesn't get added to the device at install time in sandbox.

Comment: Apple doesn't provide much documentation on sandbox. The best resource I know of is here: https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-subscription-testing-on-ios